# TabHost , TabSpec - onclick implementation

Tags: android

i am working with TabHost , TabSpec .i want to do some actions(like onClick) when TabSpec is clicked. has anyone tried this i am able to go to another activity with "home.setIndicator("Home")...."  is it possible

Comment: have you tried it yourself? why not try and post the problem you have, if any

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Is there any problem?

Comment: what i am trying to do is try to change the TabSpec image while clicking on a specific TabSpec,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.html

**Example**

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if(TAB_1.equals(tabId)) {
       //Change first image
    }
    if(TAB_2.equals(tabId)) {
        //chnage second image ...so on
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), you'll see that it's possible to change the tab image (to show that the tab is being selected or not) by defining XML file in `res/drawable/`